# parameter naming in JavaScript filter() method

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, filter

Ok this has been bugging me for a while now so any help would be greatly appreciated!

filter Question :

Take the following array:

```
const companies = [{name: "Company One", catagory: "Finance"}, {name: "Company Two", catagory: "Retail"}, {name: "Company Three", catagory:"Auto Shop"}];
```

When I saw a `filter()` function listed as:

```
const retailCompanies = companies.filter(company => company.catagory === 'Retail');
```

it got me asking why company.catagory and not companies.catagory as the text in the parent array would suggest? It may seem trivial but I just need to know where this altered and how the code reads this.

Thanking you!

Comment: `companies` - the array that contains all companies `company` - one item of the array. Since, the function will be called against each member, it would go over all of them.

Comment: I suggest you should change the title of your question, this is not higher order function.

Comment: consider this title changed, thank you

Answer (score 0):

`company` is the callback argument that holds the current element, you can name it whatever you want, mostly you will see people name it just `el` or they destrucutre it like this:

```
const retailCompanies = companies.filter(({ catagory }) => catagory === 'Retail');
```

`company` holds the current element of the loop, it looks like this:

`{name: "Company One", catagory: "Finance"}`

And you want to compare the `catagory` property with `'Retail'` so you need to write

`company.catagory === 'Retail'`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is higher order function, it is built-in method of array.

The filter syntax is:

```
let newArray = arr.filter(callback(element[, index, [array]])[, thisArg])
```

In your example, the `company` is the `element` in the syntax above.
The filter will run the callback function for each of given array's element until the end.

Source:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 0):

Filter function is passed a callback which is then invoked in a loop by passing the individual values from array.

So everytime your callback is run you are passed an object from your companies array like `{name: "Company One", catagory: "Finance"}` in first iteration, `{name: "Company Two", catagory: "Retail"}` in second iteration and so on.

Since you called your object `company` you use `company.category` to access the category field within this object. You can choose to name the argument to callback function anything for instance `item`

```
const retailCompanies = companies.filter(item => item.catagory === 'Retail');
```

You can think of filter function being implemented like

```
Array.prototype.filter = function(callback) {
   const arr = this;
   const res = [];
   for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      if(callback(arr[i], i)) { // call the callback function with the ith item
         res.push(arr[i]);
      }
   }
   return res;

}
```